# Drawing images with time delay

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I want to draw images on generated coords after some time delay but I got nullpointerexception. I'm trying to make that my image will move from one point to another with visible time delay.

```
public class PaintStations extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6734649580151111907L;
    private Thread thread;

    public PaintStations() {
        setSize(new Dimension(MainWindow.WIDTH, MainWindow.HEIGHT));
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    private void plot(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("cpn.png");
        g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
    }

    private void drawLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        int d = 0;

        int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
        int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);

        int dy2 = (dy << 1); 
        int dx2 = (dx << 1); 

        int ix = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1; 
        int iy = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;

        if (dy <= dx) {
            for (;;) {
                plot(g, x1, y1);
                if (x1 == x2)
                    break;
                x1 += ix;
                d += dy2;
                if (d > dx) {
                    y1 += iy;
                    d -= dx2;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (;;) {
                plot(g, x1, y1);
                if (y1 == y2)
                    break;
                y1 += iy;
                d += dx2;
                if (d > dy) {
                    x1 += ix;
                    d -= dy2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        drawLine(getGraphics(), 0, 0, 10, 10);
    }

    public void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the errors I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PaintStations.plot(PaintStations.java:27)
    at PaintStations.drawLine(PaintStations.java:44)
    at PaintStations.run(PaintStations.java:71)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

I'm testing putting image on random coords but `repaint();` doesn't work correctly. It seems that `paintComponent()` method is fired after `generateFuelStations()` end, and on screen only appears one image on last generated coords.

```
public class PaintStations extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6734649580151111907L;
    private ArrayList<Point> stationsLocation;
    private Shape region;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int stationsNumber;

    public PaintStations(Shape region, int stationsNumber) {
        setSize(new Dimension(MainWindow.WIDTH, MainWindow.HEIGHT));
        setOpaque(false);
        this.region = region;
        this.stationsNumber = stationsNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Repaint!");
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("cpn.png");
        g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
    }

    private void generateFuelStations(int stationsNumber) {
        Rectangle r = region.getBounds();
        this.stationsLocation = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<stationsNumber; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();

            do {
                x = (int) (r.getX() + rand.nextInt( (int) r.getWidth() ));
                y = (int) (r.getY() + rand.nextInt( (int) r.getHeight() ));
            } while(!region.contains(x,y));
            System.out.println("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
            stationsLocation.add(new Point(x,y));
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        generateFuelStations(stationsNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a Thread for animation. Instead you should use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Then when the Timer fires you adjust the properties (x1/y1, x2, y2) valus of the image you want to move and invoke `repaint()` on your component. These properties should be properties of the class.

Don't use getGraphics(). Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method and then you use the Graphics object passed to the method for your custom painting. So basically, I think, your `paintComponent()` method should invoke your `drawLine(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your getGraphics() call returns null. You should ovverride the paintComponent() method instead of calling getGraphics() and update with repaint().

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `getGraphics()` says

> Creates a graphics context for this component. This method will return null if this component is currently not displayable.

Your class is not displayable because you make no call to `super()` in your constructor.  Always make a call to the parent class's constructor when you extend a class.

Note:  This particular part of the documentation wasn't easy to find.  When you're looking at a method and it says it overrides a parent class's method, always look at the parent class's method as well, because often (read: most of the time) an overridden method will have a call to the parent's method.  Digging through the documentation will often give you an answer to why your program isn't working, though don't forget to also scrutinize your own code from time to time as well.