Timer for reproduces movement
I’m trying to program the game "Gravity Guys", in this game the player runs forward and can change the gravity only when it touches surface. There is an enemy player following him and if he touches the main player the game ends. I want to program this enemy player giving him the same method as main player, but I want the enemy player to make the same moves as the main player after 3 seconds, in this case if the main player is blocked the enemy player touches it and the game will end. Do not know how to replicate this movement after 3 seconds, advice?
public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter{

    Handler handler;
    private long startTime = -1;  // Impostiamo un valore iniziale non valido

    public KeyInput(Handler handler){
        this.handler=handler;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key=e.getKeyCode(); //ogni comando ha una key

        for(int i =0 ; i<handler.object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject= handler.object.get(i);

            if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player) {
            
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && ((Player) tempObject).canSwitchGravity ) {
                    tempObject.setGravityInverted(!tempObject.isGravityInverted());
                    ((Player) tempObject).canSwitchGravity = false;
                               
                }
            }
            if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Enemy){
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && ((Enemy) tempObject).canSwitchGravity ) {
                    
                    if (startTime == -1) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    
                    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;


                    if (elapsedTime >= 2900) {
                        tempObject.setGravityInverted(!tempObject.isGravityInverted());
                        ((Enemy) tempObject).canSwitchGravity = false;
                        startTime = -1;
                    }  
                }
            }

            if(key== KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                System.exit(1);
                
            }
            
        }
    }

This method works that if I press space and a variable that I set in another method is true then the player jumps . I would like the enemy player to do the same but a few seconds later (for example 3s)

You could keep track of the player actions in a kind of "event log" (basically a queue) and the enemy pops from the beginning and executes every action that was done before - with a certain delay. However, I'm not sure this is the best approach since that would basically mean the enemy makes the same mistakes as the player, e.g. if the player gets stuck for 2 seconds and then moves, the enemy would get stuck for 2 seconds too.

Is not problem if the enemy get stuck too, but i don't understand how i can implement this delay

Have you read the documentation of Timer?

While https://stackoverflow.com/a/30056064/105474 answers two questions, the first question it answers similar to yours.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
